# Change BTM tlog file location

Tags: java, jta, bitronix

We're using `org.codehaus.btm:btm:2.1.4` for our tests and we're seeing these files appear in our maven module directory (which is the working directory):

- `btm1.tlog`
- `btm2.tlog`

I'd like them to be created in another directory, for example in `target/btmlogs/`. How can I do configure BTM to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to configure the TransactionManager. [Relevant part of the configuration](https://github.com/bitronix/btm/wiki/Transaction-manager-configuration#setting-values-directly-on-the-configuration-object)

Do it in a file called `src/main/resources/bitronix-default-config.properties`. Something like this:

```
# Avoid warnings in test log
bitronix.tm.serverId=foo-bar
# Disable tlog files
bitronix.tm.journal=null
# In case the journal is enabled locally, avoid that the btm1.tlog and btm2.tlog files are created in the module's directory
# causing gitignore, mvn clean and IDE indexing issues
bitronix.tm.journal.disk.logPart1Filename=target/btm/btm1.tlog
bitronix.tm.journal.disk.logPart2Filename=target/btm/btm2.tlog
```

Comment: `poolingDataSource.getDriverProperties().setProperty("bitronix.tm.journal.disk.logPart1Filename", "target/btm/my-btm1.tlog");` causes a `bitronix.tm.utils.PropertyException: no readable property 'bitronix' in class 'bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.lrc.LrcXADataSource'`

Comment: Using `TransactionManagerServices.getConfiguration()` instead, causes `IllegalStateException: cannot change the configuration while the transaction manager is running`. Doing them in a static constructor instead of at the beginning of every JUnit test makes all but the first test write to the wrong directory (so ignore the property).

Comment: Fixed. I've added the file in which to add those props in the answer: bitronix-default-config.properties.